# jquery not working in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am working with wordpress multisite, trying to add below code to a page by copying it to the text view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetTel() {
     $("#showtel").load("http://example.com/tel.php?id=2");
    return false;
}
</script>

<div id="showtel"></div>
```

I used the same code in a testing php file and it works, but when adding to the wordpress page it doesn't work.

Comment: Please Close the load function. You are missing a close bracket there.

Comment: After closing the parentheses, you should read up on how to *really* add javascript in Wordpress, how the no-conflict stuff works etc.

Comment: Sorry missed the bracket by mistake here, already added in my code

Comment: Open your console, does it say *"$ is not defined"* etc.

Answer (score 0):

Close the **)** first bracket (parentheses)

```
function GetTel() {
    $("#showtel").load("http://example.com/tel.php?id=2");
                                                       ^^^
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry missed the bracket by mistake here, already added in my code